# Ace Code editor disappears onclick

Tags: javascript, html, web, polymer-1.0, ace-editor

I have embedded ace-widget in my page.I have added a button which reads the editor session value using getvalue() method. The editor disappears after I click the button.What could be the cause of error? Please find screenshot in the link below.

```
<ace-widget id="editor1" initial-focus theme="ace/theme/monokai" mode="ace/mode/json" softtabs="true" wrap="true">
            This is a nice widget... and we are writing a long text here to show the effects of the `wrap` attribute.
          </ace-widget>       
          <paper-button raised class="custom indigo" onclick="myrun()">Run</paper-button>             
          <paper-textarea label="autoresizing textarea input"></paper-textarea>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function myrun(){
              var editor = ace.edit("editor1");
              var myVar = editor.getSession().getValue();
              myVar= myVar.replace(/\d+/, '');
              myVar = myVar.substring(0,myVar.indexOf('XXXXXXX'));
              alert(myVar);
            }
          </script>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMxtN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementById("editor1").editor` instead of `ace.edit("editor1")`

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<link   rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Download/polymer-cdn/master/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<link   rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/LostInBrittany/ace-widget/master/ace-widget.html">
<link   rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Download/polymer-cdn/master/lib/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">


<ace-widget id="editor1" initial-focus theme="ace/theme/monokai" mode="ace/mode/json" softtabs="true" wrap="true">
            This is a nice widget... and we are writing a long text here to show the effects of the `wrap` attribute.
</ace-widget>       
<paper-button raised class="custom indigo" onclick="myrun()">Run</paper-button>             
<paper-textarea label="autoresizing textarea input"></paper-textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myrun() {
        var editor = document.getElementById("editor1").editor
        var myVar = editor.session.getValue();
        myVar= myVar.replace(/\d+/, '');
        myVar = myVar.substring(0,myVar.indexOf('XXXXXXX'));
        alert(myVar);
    }
</script>
```